# My manager wants me to leave earlier than my two-weeks....?

Tags: united-states, human-resources, manager, exit-interview, exit-planning

My mind was made up and accepted a job offer. I called my manager to give him my two-week notice and he obviously wasn't thrilled of the prospect of another person leaving. (We've had very high turnover in the department). He insisted he would get with our department VP to see if the company can match the offer (I knew they couldn't but I wouldn't stay for any amount they offered me).

I gave the standard two-week notice and sent out an email and had it in writing. Couple of hours later my manager tells me due to payroll/HR policy, they prefer I leave at the end of the next week (13 days instead of full two-weeks). This didn't sit right with me, I told him I would feel comfortable giving my full two-weeks. He kept insisting and I gave in and agreed to 13 days and said I would speak with HR when I got back from business travel. He told me it is fine and he ran this through HR and everything was good.

I get back and call our HR director and asked of this ''policy'' and she seemed puzzled and said while it's nice to leave at the end of a work week, it wasn't mandatory. She asked me if I'd like to modify my last day, I'd need to speak with payroll and they can change it for me as they already put my last day at the end of the week.

As you can imagine, I was furious; I thought me and my manager had a good relationship and I even offered to finish up projects I'm working on and tell my colleagues where the projects stand. Should I confront him about this? I guess at the same time I feel this only strengthen my decision to leave.

Comment: What's the specific problem with doing one less day ?

Comment: I lose an extra day of pay.......?

Comment: Couple of hours later my manager tells me due to payroll/HR policy, they *prefer* I leave at the end of the next week (13 days instead of full two-weeks).  I get back and call our HR director and asked of this ''policy'' and she seemed puzzled and said while it's nice to leave at the end of a work week, it wasn't mandatory.  Prefer doesn't sound mandatory to me either.  Finishing on a Friday makes sense to me.  Is it really worth blowing a fufu valve over 1 day?

Comment: In a lot of companies, you are escorted out of the door when handing in your two weeks notice.

Comment: @PieterB, I have seen that quite often, but in all cases the exiting employee got the two weeks of pay anyway, often referred to as gardening leave.  In this case, OP is losing a days pay.  In some jurisdictions being forced out before your noticed day would be considered getting fired by the company which is a critical difference

Comment: @LegendofLegends  Can you tell your new job you're available a day sooner than planned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I confront him about this?

In comments on another question, you indicated that you are in the United States in Texas. Texas is an at-will employment state. I'm assuming that is still the relevant locale.

If you are in the US, in an at-will state, it may not be nice, and it may make you furious, but you can be let go without any notice period at all, or with a reduced notice period. Your desire to continue working for two weeks doesn't matter.

Instead of angrily "confronting" your manager, perhaps HR would be willing to talk with him if you ask nicely. They may be able to convince him to grant your two week notice period.

Comment: This answer is accurate and for one day it may not matter, but I believe in the US, if you are forced out (without pay) before the day you specify in your resignation, that constitutes termination which changes the rules and responsibilities

Comment: Nothing related to at-will changes. The employer can terminate you at any time and for any reason, unless that reason is illegal under state and federal law. Our personal opinions on the matter don't matter. What matters is what the prevailing laws dictate.

Comment: Unemployment insurance is the biggest.  My understanding is that the company is generally responsible for unemployment insurance costs related to the terminated employee.  For one day, not that big a deal but could become problematic if they do that to all employees who resign

Comment: If OP said I quit as of a certain day and the company makes him leave before then(without paying for those days) then I believe he has been fired because the company took control of the final day

Answer (score 29):

Getting "furious" over this seems a bit of an overreaction - especially as there's a good chance your boss has simply misunderstood HR policy rather than being malicious.

That said - it is also not uncommon for employees/employers to come to an agreement that the employee leaves earlier than their notice period when they are resigning, for various reasons - although, it would normally be more mutual than your situation as described.

At the end of the day, you are going to what sounds like a much better paid job, and you now have a three-day weekend in between to refresh and recharge. Confronting your boss when you are already leaving isn't going to achieve anything, and will only create acrimony and burn your bridge.

Answer (score 14):

How badly do you need an extra day of pay?

If the situation is not *"I won't be able to pay my rent and/or feed my children without it"* then I don't think there's anything worth being furious about here.

You wanted to leave anyway, so just shrug about your former manager's strange behavior and enjoy your day off.

Comment: Well, the fact he lied to me and blamed HR was what angered me

Comment: @LegendofLegends - Based on comments and other answers, I don't think anyone else sees this as a clear, deliberate lie. Maybe just a misunderstanding or misinterpretation. Or, at worst, a poor word choice (saying they "prefer" something). If there are details that make you think this was malicious or a deliberate manipulative lie for some specific malicious goal, maybe you can edit those details into your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to confront your boss.

Assuming that your contract says that there must be a notice period of 2 weeks on either side, email him the following:

"I just spoke with HR. They said that leaving in two weeks wasn't a problem payroll-wise. So I told them not to change my departure date.

So just let me know if you still want me to leave in 13 days, despite the fact that you will still be paying me for 14 days. "

Then print out a copy of that email that you take home for your personal records. The same with HR. Confirm by email that the date wasn't changed. Then print out that email to keep for your personal records.